# Android app "Unknown error" when uploading photo

Tags: bug, android-app

Spent a half hour on this. Android 5.1.1 latest version SE app (Play Store won't let me update so latest).

Tried to upload photo into an answer. "Something went wrong".  Did tricks to reduce photo size to 275k -- same.

45k rep on the stack.

Here is the photo..... *oh wait*.

How do I solve?

Comment: Don't use the app?

Comment: See if you get an error uploading the image on the mobile site.

Comment: You can upload to external host, e.g. directly to imgur.com.

Comment: Sorry, am I in the wrong place to report bugs? I was able to workaround but figured someone would want to fix this.

Comment: You're not in the wrong place but there's no current development being done on either version of the app, so the easiest solution is to not use the app. You do ask "How do I solve" - you don't solve bug reports, the staff do... just not right now.

Comment: I noticed the July '17 last update. The problem, then, is one of expectations. Right now the apps are being proffered in the app store, creating an expectation of currency. Disabusing people of that expectation seems like it could take a lot of bandwidth in meta.

Comment: I use and am very happy with the iOS app... the problem is that the Android app was never as advanced or "finished" as the iOS one. If you look through the questions here, there may even be one that's identical to this from a while back... that said, if I had an Android, I'd be using the site in Firefox, so that I could use their script manager and have similar functionality on mobile as on a desktop, tiny screen be damned.